# Get all filenames from FileUpload control on Client Side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome

With the `asp:FileUpload Control`, `Allow Multiple = True`. When I run the following javascript script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=fileUploader.ClientID%>').change(function () {
            debugger;
            $('#<%=lblFileNames.ClientID%>').text("Files: ");
            var path = $(this).val();
            var i;
            var files = path.split(',');
            var indFiles = "Files: ";
            for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                files[i] = files[i].substring(files[i].lastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
                indFiles = indFiles + i + ":" + files[i] + "; ";
            }
            $('#<%=lblFileNames.ClientID%>').text(indFiles);
        })
    })
</script>
```

`var path = $(this).val()` on IE/Mozilla returns all the files I selected delimited, but on chrome returns only the first file selected.

**Questions**

1) Why does Chrome do this as opposed to the behavior in IE/Mozilla browsers.

2) Is there a way around this on client side? I know a server-side "solution", but for my purpose, I need this done via javascript on client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the list of files provided in `this.files`

```
        var files = [];
        var indFiles = "Files: ";
        for (i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
            files[i] = this.files[i].name;                
            indFiles = indFiles + i + ":" + files[i] + "; ";
        }
        $('#<%=lblFileNames.ClientID%>').text(indFiles);
```

Comment: See edit for reason why I edited. But your idea was the idea that resulted in the correct behavior I expected. Marking answer, however I am still curious why chrome does that in my question.